# ¿Cómo comparar modelos logit anidados mediante ANOVA en R?

Tags: r, anova, glm

Tengo dos modelos **logit binomial**:

- Modelo A:

```
modelo_logit_viv <- glm( SAP ~sexo + edad + peso + niv_est + enf_cron +  sit_lab +
                           frec_act_fis   + GHQ_12 + ingreso_eq +
                           n_dormitorios + cont_indus +    delincuencia, # variables de estudio
                         data = datos_modelo, family = binomial(link = "logit"),na.action = "na.omit")
```

- Modelo B (modelo anidado de A):

```
modelo_logit <- glm(SAP ~ sexo + edad + peso + niv_est + enf_cron  +  sit_lab + 
                       frec_act_fis   + ingreso_eq + GHQ_12, 
                       data = modelo_logit_viv$model, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

`c(edad, peso, ingreso_eq, GHQ_12)` Son variables contínuas, el resto son variables categóricas (factor).

Quiero analizar si las características de la vivienda (variables de estudio) tienen influencia en el estado de salud auto-percibido (SAP). Todas las variables son significaivas en ambos modelos. Sin embargo, quiero realizar un análisis de la varianza (ANOVA) entre estos dos modelos para **comprobar que el modelo B es mejor que el modelo B**. Así que ejecuto:

`anova(modelo_logit,modelo_logit_viv)`

Y obtengo la siguiente tabla:

```
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance
1     16805      15439            
2     16802      15420  3   18.644
```

¿Puede la interpretación de esta tabla decirme si hay una influencia entre las características de la vivienda y el estado de salud?

Otra forma de formular esta pregunta es: ¿ Es el `18.644` el estadístico de prueba F que debo comparar con la tabla F de Snedecor para determinar si se acepta o no la hipótesis nula de que existen diferencia de medias entre ambos modelos?

Si no, ¿cómo puedo comparar estos dos modelos con un ANOVA en R?

Comment: Formulé esta misma pregunta en Cross Validated y ya me la han contestado, dejo el enlace. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462700/how-to-compaire-nested-logit-models-using-anova-in-r ¿Debería auto-contestarme traduciendo aquí la respuesta que me han dado?

Comment: Hola Luis, sería bueno que lo hagas, así trasladamos este conocimiento a nuestra lengua madre. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El término de desviación que vemos al ejecutar `anova(modelo_logit,modelo_logit_viv)` **es la diferencia entre la suma de los errores de la predicción**, así que si el `modelo_logit` perdice mejor que el `modelo_logit_viv`, la desviación debería disminuir, como es el caso.

Esto sugiere que efectivamente las variables de estudio tienen poder explicativo o alguna asociación con la variable dependiente `SAP`.

Podemos comprobar esto mediante el test **Chi-cuadrado** que viene implementado en `anova()`. Un ejemplo con el `dataframe` `iris`:

```
data = iris
data$Species=ifelse(data$Species=="versicolor",1,0)
full_model = glm(Species ~ .,data=data,family=binomial)
red_model = glm(Species ~ Sepal.Width,data=data,family=binomial)

anova(red_model,full_model,test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: Species ~ Sepal.Width
Model 2: Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)  
1       148     151.93                       
2       145     145.07  3   6.8562  0.07662
```

Por otra parte, si las variables de estudio incluidas en el modelo son significativas bajo el test de Wald (podemos ver esto ejecutando `summary(modelo_logit_viv)`) **el ratio de verosimilitud debería ser similar**, así que de paso calculamos también el pseudo R^2 de McFadden:

```
modelo_nulo <- glm(SAP~1, family = "binomial",data = datos_modelo)

pseudo_R_viv_signif <- 1 - logLik(modelo_logit_viv)/logLik(modelo_nulo)
pseudo_R_viv_signif  # 0.49

pseudo_R <- 1 - logLik(modelo_logit)/logLik(modelo_nulo) # 0.48
pseudo_R
```

Vemos que los valores son muy similares `c(0.49,0.48)` y el test de Chi-cuadrado en mi modelo también es significativo. **Podemos concluir entonces que las variables de estudio sí son relevantes** a la hora de explicar el estado de salud (`SAP`)